# When setting both the set bit and reset bit to 1 in GPIOx_BSRR, will the output be high level or low level?

Tags: stm32, gpio

In the GPIO peripheral of STM32, there is a GPIO port bit set/reset register (GPIOx_BSRR). The lower 16 bits set the corresponding pin output to a high level, and the upper 16 bits reset the corresponding pin output to a low level. I'm curious about the outcome when simultaneously setting and resetting the same pin. What will be the final effect? Why?

The result of my own experimentation is that the output will be at a high level.

Answer (score 0):

The output will be at a high level according to the reference manual: Note: If both BSx and BRx are set, BSx (bit set) takes priority.

Comment: Why would you ever do this? It has no practical purpose at all, and you risk potential undefined behavior on other hardware, and undefined state of pin could mean hardware damage if you get extra unlucky (depending on what's connected to that pin). Why try to set the same pin both high and low at the same time?